# Можно ли совместить html и картинки в один файл?

Tags: html, изображения

У меня есть html документ, который содержит примерно 20 картинок. Все эти файлы лежат в одной папке. Транспортировка неудобная, нужно перемещать все файлы одновременно. есть ли способ совместить это все в один исполняемый файл, который бы открывал html?

Comment: ...ш...ш...што?

Comment: Возможно я как-то неправильно описал желаемое. Хотелось бы иметь просто один файл. html со встроенными картирками.

Comment: можно конвертировать изображения в base64

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Comment: Кажется IE мог сохранять страницу в один файл. Web-архив `.mht`, вот.

Comment: Как вариант - встроить в CSS в виде base64, а сам css внедрить в html, все это можно автоматизировать с помощью gulp и плагинов.

Comment: Конечно можно! Конвертируете изображение в base64 (насколько я помню) и суете в svg. Но зачем???

Comment: @Michael написано же зачем - чтобы не таскать кучу файлов.

Comment: А вариант закинуть картинки во внешнюю файлопомойку и оттуда картинки подключать на страницу не рассматривается? Лучше чем потом копать в файле со вставками base64

Comment: `.chm` еще как вариант (в продолжение темы `.mht`).

Comment: @alexolut, Opera тоже вроде бы раньше умела. Как сейчас - не в курсе, давно не пользуюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Можно в `img` сохранять `base64`, в котором файлы изображения закодированы.

Гугл выдал один из сервисом для конвертации в base64: https://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/

После конвертации можно сразу как тег `img` скопировать и добавить на страницу.

```html
<img  width="48" height="48"  src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно упаковать все в формат CHM (он же [HTMLHelp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTMLHelp)). Под Windows откроется везде, под другими системами нужны специальные просмотрщики (в статье на Википедии есть список).

Сам когда-то пользовался утилитой htm2chm для упаковки в этот формат страниц, скачанных из интернета.